# Traveling salesman - limit the length

Tags: algorithm, julia, traveling-salesman

I'm trying to change the Traveling Salesman Problem I found on Github:

https://github.com/JuliaOpt/JuMP.jl/blob/master/examples/tsp.jl

My goal is to limit the way the salesman to 400 max.

To do so, I changed the objective to `@setObjective(m, Max, sum{x[i,j], i=1:n,j=i:n})` while adding the constraint `@addConstraint(m, sum{dist[i,j]*x[i,j],i= 1:n, j=1:n} <= 400)`. After doing so, the solver can't find no solution anymore and I didn't found mistake.

Comment: (1) This limit should not touch the objective (2) This limit won't help the solver and it's behaving exactly the same for a best tour <= 400; it just only returns infeasible if there is no such tour. (3) Incorporating this limit is just copying the objective with a less-equal + a right-hand-side.

Comment: @sascha because there is no valid solution, which does visit all points and is less then 400 the objective must be changed. I want to visit as many points as possible while traveling less then 400.

Answer (score 1):

Found the Mistake. The provided code has the constraint @constraint(m, sum(x[i,j] for j=1:n) == 2) in line 133. This makes it impossible to not visit each city. By changing this constraint to  @constraint(m, sum(x[i,j] for j=1:n) <= 2) I got my Solution.